# Transferring a working slackware router/firewall to ubuntu 20.04 - netplan configuration problems

Tags: networking, router, firewall, ubuntu-20.04

I obtained my original slackware linux on 19 3.5" floppy disks in the days when CDROMs didn't exist and have been maintaining and upggrading via text terminal ever since.
A recent thunderstorm trashed all my hardware, so I decided to modernise to Ubuntu in the rebuild.
The server software is ubuntu server 20.04 (upgraded online since) using bind9, isc-dhcp-server and iptables using edited scripts and configuration files from the old system's offline backups.

From the WAN inwards, the setup is as follows.
A Sagemcom F@st5355 router configured ipv4  10.0.0.0/24, address 10.0.0.1. DHCP4 activated, serving leases 10.0.0.100 to 10.0.0.200.
The computer's WAN single-port PCIE card interface is originally configured by subequity and later edited by text editor is /etc/netplan/00-installer-config.yaml
Which is:

```
network:
  version: 2
  ethernets:
    enp4s0:
      dhcp4: true
```

So far, so good the nameserver and gateway, routing, IP address (10.0.0.100) info all provided by the upstream hardware router via the DHCP lease.  This all works and the computer is able to access the internet, use 'apt upgrade' etc.

IPv4 forwarding enabled in /etc/sysctl.conf.

So begins the problem.
The second LAN 1GB NIC (enp3s0) is on the motherboard and the netplan configuration created with text editor is as follows.

```
network:
  version: 2
  ethernets:
    enp3s0:
      addresses:
      - 192.168.1.16/24
      routes:
        - to: 127.0.0.1
          via: 10.0.0.1
```

The problem is that no traffic finds its way from the LAN to the WAN. This is not the first cut at producing the right config for the LAN NIC. None of the instructions or tutorials I have found online provide a clear path to setting up this interface.
BTW I have since installed bind9, isc-dhcp-server and iptables, suitably edited for this system's interface names etc. Still no luck.
Peter

Comment: In addition to my answer - do you/did you purge UFW? Its vaguely possible its trampling on your firewall rules.

Answer (score 0):

I had some unusual issues with netplan and 20.04, and switching over to either 22.04 or using the classic ip configuration setup is recommended. I believe that dnsmasq would start before the network, and things went wrong

Post setting up netplan and the firewall, its probably worth testing with *static ips* on either end of the network and seeing if the two sides can ping each other.

Unfortunately, I've moved to 22.04 (and there's significant changes there) - do I can't test, and I use firewalld for management so *some* things may require translation. I've documented that [build here - its for 18.04 but I ran it through 20.04](https://journeymangeek.com/?p=196) - there's some significant changes with 22.04 (with firewalld running nftables as a backend)

My *working* config for 22.04 looks like this

```
 network:
  ethernets:
    enp1s0:
      dhcp4: true
      match:
          macaddress: XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
      set-name: wan
    enp2s0:
      dhcp4: no
    enp3s0:
      dhcp4: no
    enp4s0:
      dhcp4: no

  bridges:
    lan:
      dhcp4: no
      addresses:
       - 192.168.2.1/24
      interfaces:
        - enp2s0
        - enp3s0
        - enp4s0
```

Its a little different - but other than that I don't think you 'need' to set static routes any more, yours looks fine. I also choose the WAN interface and lan interfaces - though this is very much so they match the labels I stuck on the router.

I fed these into firewalld as direct rules on my old build so I believe that these should work

```
ipv4 nat POSTROUTING 0 -o  enp1s0 -j MASQUERADE
ipv4 filter FORWARD 0 -i br0 -o  enp1s0 -j ACCEPT
ipv4 filter FORWARD 0 -i enp1s0 -o br0 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

Answer (score 0):

While waiting for an answer, I was doing more searching and found this post.

https://www.networkreverse.com/2020/06/how-to-build-linux-router-with-ubuntu.html

There I found enough to set up my basic Ubuntu router. Basically a bare-bones connection WAN <--> LAN was established.  I then started 'sudo apt upgrade' and went and had a cuppa.  Came back, rebooted into Ubuntu V:22.04 and apt installed isc-dhcp-server and bind9 and installed edited conf files from my Slackware setup.

My netplan config files are now:

```
00-installer-config.yaml
```

{
network:
version: 2
ethernets:
enp4s0:
dhcp4: true
}

```
99-enp3s0-config.yaml
    network:
    version: 2
    ethernets:
      enp3s0:
        addresses:
        - 192.168.1.16/24
        nameservers:
          addresses:
          - 203.12.160.35
          - 203.12.160.36
```

The result communicates albeit slowly which is puzzling because the same programs running on identical hardware as the slackware setup which was very fast. No doubt I will find some silly mistake in the iptables configs.
Meanwhile, I hope my travails are useful to someone else.